# Should I keep my I-797 (USCIS Approval Notice) even after I obtained the corresponding F1 visa?

Tags: usa, student-visa

I obtained an F1 visa in the United States. In the process, I have received a I-797 (USCIS Approval Notice) for my F1 reinstatement:

[image]

Is there any point in keeping the I-797, or can I safely throw it away?

Comment: I keep everything original. You never know when something in the past might come into dispute, and there was a simple official document that could immediately clear everything up.

Comment: @ouflak wouldn't the F1 be enough to clear everything up?

Comment: If it still exists, sure.

Comment: How long did you wait for your approval?

Comment: @Yan224: Sorry, I do not recall, that was over five years ago :/

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it, at least until the corresponding visa expires. If you really feel compelled to discard the physical paper now, then keeping a scanned copy should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, in which case this could be I-797 be useful, aside from loss of passport (on reaching the F1 visa is stamped) or I-20?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: It's difficult to predict exactly *when* this form might be useful to you. But loss of other documents could certainly be one case.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep it.

For example, one of the requirements for Adjustment of Status (the process of getting US permanent residency from within the US) is that you've never been out of status in the US in any past trips (except if you are an Immediate Relative of a US citizen in which case you don't have to be in status). So if there's even a remote possibility of you applying for this (for example, if you will be in the US on a work visa and apply for permanent residency from the US) at some later point in your life, you want to make sure to retain all I-20s and I-797s to prove you were continuously in status.